# How can I get alternate values in a for-each loop?

Tags: java

How can I get alternate values in a for-each loop?

```
String [] yesBank = {"bdshfdhbck", "gsdhkcvdcjh", "fbdsjkfdsfj", "njjhsdfbjsfggsj"};
for(String arrayOFWord : yesBank)
{
    System.out.println(arrayOFWord);
}
```

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "alternative values"?

Comment: @KevinO "alternate" not "alternative". But your question is valid.

Comment: Does that mean every other value?

Comment: If so, that's not possible with an enhanced for loop because enhanced iterates through every element of a collection sequentially

Comment: why do you want to use foreach only? any specific reason,if not you can try using basic for loop within array length and incrementing by 2 instead of one

Comment: I would aggree with @faris, the index loop would be a better option to solve these problems since you can control the increment.

Comment: Yeah enhanced loops were made for the very specific purpose of complete iteration. By doing this you are just running a regular loop again essentially with more effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a flag;

```
    String [] yesBank = {"bdshfdhbck", "gsdhkcvdcjh", "fbdsjkfdsfj", "njjhsdfbjsfggsj"};
    boolean flag = true;
    for(String arrayOFWord : yesBank)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            System.out.println(arrayOFWord);
        }
        flag = !flag;
    }
```

This is for odd elements. For even elements, start with `flag = false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some count variable, because the alternative values are either in even or odd indexes.

try this, for even idexes

```
String [] yesBank = {"bdshfdhbck", "gsdhkcvdcjh", "fbdsjkfdsfj", "njjhsdfbjsfggsj"};
int count=0;
for(String arrayOFWord : yesBank)
{
    if((count++)%2 == 0)
        System.out.println(arrayOFWord);    
}
```

Comment: That is literally just turning the enhanced loop back into a regular for loop

Comment: I am fixing to help him achieve  what he wants.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod these comments are more for the OP than yourself. The OP should have said "loop" instead of restricting to "for-each loop". There are places where one type of loop fits better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for even indexes:

```
String [] yesBank = {"bdshfdhbck", "gsdhkcvdcjh", "fbdsjkfdsfj", "njjhsdfbjsfggsj"};
        for(String arrayOFWord : yesBank)
        {
        if (Arrays.asList(yesBank).indexOf(arrayOFWord)%2  ==  0) System.out.println(arrayOFWord);    
        }
```